# TypeError: c.attr(...) is undefined

Tags: javascript, woocommerce

Hello i have a problem with my site, when i try add product to cart with the button in single product page it only stay loading and it dont add the product and it send me this error to the console.

```
TypeError: c.attr(...) is undefined[Saber más] xoo-wsc-public.min.js:1:4146

    <anonymous> https://www.mutantshop.mx/assets/scripts/side-cart-woocommerce/public/js/xoo-wsc-public.min.js:1 dispatch2jQuery
```

I try edit the source code but without succes, for see the live problem please enter to the next link and try add product to cart and open the console for see the error.
 https://www.mutantshop.mx/tienda/mutant-caseina-micellar-4-lbs

here is te souce file  xoo-wsc-public.min.js;

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(o){"use strict";function t(){if(window.wc_checkout_params&&"1"===wc_checkout_params.is_checkout){if(0===o("form.checkout").length)return void location.reload();o(document.body).trigger("update_checkout")}window.wc_add_to_cart_params&&window.wc_add_to_cart_params.is_cart&&"1"===wc_add_to_cart_params.is_cart&&o(document.body).trigger("wc_update_cart")}function c(t){var c=o(".xoo-wsc-modal , body"),a="xoo-wsc-active";"show"==t?c.addClass(a):"hide"==t?c.removeClass(a):c.toggleClass("xoo-wsc-active"),o(".xoo-wsc-updating").hide()}function a(){var t=o(".xoo-wsc-header").outerHeight(),c=o(".xoo-wsc-footer").outerHeight(),a=o(window).height();o(".xoo-wsc-body").height(a-(t+c))}function e(){o(".xoo-wsc-updating").show()}function r(t){o.each(t.target.classList,function(t,c){"xoo-wsc-container"==c||"xoo-wsc-close"!=c&&"xoo-wsc-opac"!=c&&"xoo-wsc-basket"!=c&&"xoo-wsc-cont"!=c||o(".xoo-wsc-modal , body").removeClass("xoo-wsc-active")})}function n(t,a){o(document.body).trigger("adding_to_cart",[t,a]),o.ajax({url:xoo_wsc_localize.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace("%%endpoint%%","xoo_wsc_add_to_cart"),type:"POST",data:o.param(a),success:function(a){!function(o){if(1!=xoo_wsc_localize.atc_icons)return;o.find(".xoo-wsc-icon-atc").attr("class","xoo-wsc-icon-checkmark xoo-wsc-icon-atc")}(t),a.fragments?o(document.body).trigger("added_to_cart",[a.fragments,a.cart_hash,t]):a.error?(s("error",a.error),c("show")):console.log(a)}})}function s(t,c){o(".xoo-wsc-notice").html(c).attr("class","xoo-wsc-notice").addClass("xoo-wsc-nt-"+t),o(".xoo-wsc-notice-box").fadeIn("fast"),clearTimeout(a);var a=setTimeout(function(){o(".xoo-wsc-notice-box").fadeOut("slow")},2e3)}o(document.body).on("wc_fragment_refresh",e),o(document.body).on("wc_fragments_refreshed wc_fragments_loaded",function(){a()}),xoo_wsc_localize.added_to_cart||o(document.body).trigger("wc_fragment_refresh"),o(document.body).on("xoo_wsc_cart_updated",t),o(".xoo-wsc-basket").on("click",c),xoo_wsc_localize.trigger_class&&o("."+xoo_wsc_localize.trigger_class).on("click",c),a(),o(window).resize(function(){a()}),function(){if(xoo_wsc_localize.added_to_cart){var t=!1;o(document).on("wc_fragments_refreshed",function(){t||(setTimeout(c,1,"show"),t=!0)})}}(),o(document).on("added_to_cart",function(a,e,r,n){1==xoo_wsc_localize.auto_open_cart&&setTimeout(c,1,"show"),1==xoo_wsc_localize.atc_reset&&function(t){o(".xoo-wsc-icon-atc",t).remove();var c=t.parents("form.cart").find(".qty");c.length>0&&c.val(c.attr("min")||1),o(".added_to_cart").remove()}(n),t()}),o("body").on("click",".xoo-wsc-close , .xoo-wsc-opac",function(o){o.preventDefault(),r(o)}),o("body").on("click",".xoo-wsc-cont",function(t){var c=o.trim(o(this).attr("href"));"#"!=c&&c||(t.preventDefault(),r(t))}),o(document).on("click",".xoo-wsc-remove",function(t){t.preventDefault(),e();var c,a,r=o(this).parents(".xoo-wsc-product").data("xoo_wsc");c=r,a=0,o.ajax({url:xoo_wsc_localize.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace("%%endpoint%%","xoo_wsc_update_cart"),type:"POST",data:{cart_key:c,new_qty:a},success:function(t){if(t.fragments){var c=t.fragments,a=t.cart_hash;if(o.each(t.fragments,function(t,c){o(t).replaceWith(c),o(t).stop(!0).css("opacity","1").unblock()}),wc_cart_fragments_params){var e=wc_cart_fragments_params.ajax_url.toString()+"-wc_cart_hash";sessionStorage.setItem(wc_cart_fragments_params.fragment_name,JSON.stringify(c)),localStorage.setItem(e,a),sessionStorage.setItem(e,a)}o(document.body).trigger("wc_fragments_loaded"),o(document.body).trigger("xoo_wsc_cart_updated")}else s("error",t.error)}})}),1==xoo_wsc_localize.ajax_atc&&o(document).on("submit","form.cart",function(t){t.preventDefault(),e();var c=o(this),a=c.find('button[type="submit"]');!function(o){if(1!=xoo_wsc_localize.atc_icons)return;0!==o.find(".xoo-wsc-icon-atc").length?o.find(".xoo-wsc-icon-atc").attr("class","xoo-wsc-icon-spinner2 xoo-wsc-icon-atc xoo-wsc-active"):o.append('<span class="xoo-wsc-icon-spinner2 xoo-wsc-icon-atc xoo-wsc-active"></span>')}(a);var r=c.serializeArray(),s=!1;if(o.each(r,function(o,t){if(("product_id"===t.name||"add-to-cart"===t.name)&&t.value)return s=!0,!1}),!s)var i=c.attr("action").match(/add-to-cart=([0-9]+)/),_=!!i&&i[1];if(a.attr("name")&&"add-to-cart"==a.attr("name")&&a.attr("value"))_=a.attr("value");_&&r.push({name:"add-to-cart",value:_}),r.push({name:"action",value:"xoo_wsc_add_to_cart"}),n(a,r)})});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cart form is missing action prop.
If you open the developer console and check for the form of the cart it is missing property 'action'.

[image]

and the xoo-wsc-public.min.js file is trying to match on property 'action' which leads to this error.

Comment: it is not working on home page, right? Am i missing anything? Which place are you referring when you are saying it is working?

Comment: try go to homepage www.mutantshop.mx and add one product, it works fine. But if you go to product single page and try add the error appear.

Comment: On homapge you are not using form for different product, on click of the product you are making an ajax call to https://www.mutantshop.mx/?wc-ajax=add_to_cart that is why it is working. If you add action prop to form, it will work as well.

Comment: the form looks like `<form class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` right now, add property tag like `<form class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/add-to-cart">`

Comment: SOURCE CODE:   `<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>
<form class="cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>code`

Comment: I have added to the line action="/add-to-cart but it doesnt work, could you see?

Comment: it is working, I checked, hard refresh the page and try.

Comment: Its works fine now!!! thanks!!! now have a new problem, when you add a product in single page view and returns to home page the cart appear in blank

Comment: I can't help you with that as I don't know php, if my answer helped you solve your original question, consider accepting it, thanks :)